# SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-artemis

I generated a CSR with the following command:

```
openssl req -new -out activemq.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout activemq.key -config req.conf
```

I received back `my-cer.cer` after submitting my CSR, from which I created a JKS keystore:

```
keytool -importcert -noprompt -alias server -file my-cer.cer -keypass $KEY_PASS -keystore server-keystore.jks -storepass $STORE_PASS -storetype JKS
```

Similarly made a client JKS keystore with the CA.cer file.
But when I am trying to connect to broker on port 61616, I get this error on ActiveMQ Artemis broker -

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /127.0.0.1:65172: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme.
```

On the client side:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:186) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:454) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:637) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:296) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1343) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:519) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:458) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:383) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:213) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:291) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
```

Acceptor:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/Users/subhidh/Desktop/ssl/server-keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=securepass</acceptor>
```

URL used in `jndi.properties`:

```
tcp://127.0.0.1:61616?sslEnabled=true&trustStorePath=/Users/subhidh/Desktop/ssl/truststore.jks&trustStorePassword=securepass
```

Java Version - OpenJDK 17.0.5 2022-10-18 LTS

ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0

I searched for this issue - most of the people are saying to use RSA instead of DSA so I checked the cer with:

```
openssl x509 -in my-cer.cer -text
```

And it said:

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Here is the output after setting `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.561 IST|SSLCipher.java:1870|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.563 IST|SSLCipher.java:2024|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.563 IST|ServerNameExtension.java:529|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.563 IST|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.563 IST|MaxFragExtension.java:459|Ignore unavailable max_fragment_length extension
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.563 IST|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.565 IST|AlpnExtension.java:383|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.565 IST|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.567 IST|EncryptedExtensions.java:137|Produced EncryptedExtensions message (
"EncryptedExtensions": [
  "supported_groups (10)": {
    "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
  }
]
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.568 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.569 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.569 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.571 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.571 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.572 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.572 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.572 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.573 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.573 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.573 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.574 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.575 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.575 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.575 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.575 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.576 IST|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.576 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1084|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.576 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1094|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.578 IST|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): No available authentication scheme (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:972)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:961)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1246)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1182)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:840)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:801)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1549)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1395)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:266)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:536)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544)
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:387)
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:213)
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:291)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)}

)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.583 IST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.585 IST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.585 IST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|63|Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)|2023-04-21 02:19:17.588 IST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
2023-04-21 02:19:17,591 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /127.0.0.1:52212: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme.
```

Comment: A TLS server's keystore must contain both a privatekey _and_ matching certificate in the _same entry_. Did/does your `server-keystore.jks` contain a privatekey in alias `server`? Check `keytool -list -keystore server-keystore.jks -alias server`. If not, dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68284274/java-ssl-tls-no-available-authentication-scheme . PS: the log you uploaded doesn't include the initialization of the KeyManager -- look at that and I bet you'll find no privatekey was loaded from the keystore.

Comment: Never mind; now that we know you used `openssl` to generate the (private)key we know it isn't in the JKS. keytool cannot directly use an OpenSSL privatekey. Instead you must use `openssl pkcs12 -export` to combine the privatekey and cert into PKCS12, which you can either convert to JKS or use directly in any Java since about 2016 -- this has been asked and answered a hundred times, search for 'convert PEM key to Java'. OR use the software from www.keystore-explorer.org to read OpenSSL key PLUS cert(s) into Java keystore.

Comment: However, static connectors are not working now. It is throwing this error - ```unable to authorise cluster control: AMQ219016: Connection failure detected. Unblocking a blocking call that will never get a response.``` I have added static cluster config above in the question

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, can you please look onto the above query?

Comment: I recommend you ask a _new_ question about the inability to authorise the cluster control, and post an answer for what you did to resolve the original issue and mark it as correct. Each question on Stack Overflow is meant to cover just _one_ issue. You're using this as a kind of catch-all for all your SSL-related problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below command to create a `.p12` file from the signed cert and key that was created while creating the csr.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my-cer.cer -inkey activemq.key -name 'server' -out keystore.p12
```

After creating the above `.p12` file, I added that to the keystone jks using the below command, and now this works.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias server -destkeystore my_keystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass securepass -destalias server
```